# Stress Energy Tensor VS Moment Map

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, classical-field-theory

The stress-energy tensor can be a map of killing vector fields to conserved currents. To be more precise this happens by contraction $J^\mu = T^{\mu\nu}\xi_\nu$ where $\xi$ is a killing vector field.

On the other hand, in the symplectic version of Noether's theorem, we introduce the concept of a moment map, which is a map from phase space to the dual space of the Lie algebra of our symmetry group. Which can be thought of as a map of killing vector fields to conserved charges.

If the symmetry group is the group of isometries in our spacetime, then is there a way we can express the stress-energy tensor as some object that depends on the moment map?